# How to declare for the parent that the child is a shared pointer in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-c++

I have a class declaration as follows:

```
class GuiImpl : public Gui
              , protected QScrollArea
{
public:
    typedef QScrollArea Base;

public:
    GuiImpl (QWidget *parent)
    : Base(parent)
    , view(0)
    {
    }

    ~GuiImpl () {  }
```

This class is a child of `QScrollArea` and the object will be deleted by the parent. The problem is that I store the object in a `std::shared_ptr`, so when the parent is deleting the object, the counter is not decreased and the shared pointer will try to delete the object again afterwards, and this cause a bug in my code.

Is there anyway to declare the child as a `shared_ptr` for parent, so that the parent just delete the object when the reference counter is zero?

Comment: Why are you storing it in a `shared_ptr`? The parent has exclusive ownership of it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't find any other way to go around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may detach child in destructor of parent:

```
class Parent
{
  // ... Any your code
  QSharedPointer< QObject > child;

  ~Parent()
  {
    child->setParent(nullptr);
  }
};
```

But this is ugly. Instead, you should not use shared pointer, as @molbbdilo wrote in comment. You may use `QPointer` wrapper, if you don't like raw pointers.